# Rxjava AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() means UI thread?

Tags: android, rx-java

My code is like this:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe ({
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
})
```

but i got an error: *Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*
so i change it to :

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe ({
        runOnUiThread(Runnable {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
 })
 }
```

It makes sense.So I am confused.
I had thought the `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` means the code in the subscribe block runs on ui thread, but how I got this error?

Comment: Does the stacktrace point to `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`? Mb the error is in another part of the chain? Generally, yes, `mainThread()` means android's UI thread.

Comment: i don't know how to figure out whether stacktrace points to adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 13):

The problem is with the code here:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

You can not subscribe on the UI thread as you noticed, you'll get an exception:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

What you should do is to subscribe on I/O thread and observe on UI thread:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
observerable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //works Downstream
.subscribe ({
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
})
```